# Multidimensional array returns several undefined values upon iterating in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a multidimensional array that returns undefined after the last value of every sub-array. Here is my code:

```js
var bigArray = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11, 12]
];

for (i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j <= bigArray[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(bigArray[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, who taught you to use these `for` loops? A book, your teacher, some internet tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `=` part from the condition of the second loop. You tries to access an element out of the range of the array. Also declare your variables with `var, let` or `const` - in the case with `i` and `j`.

```js
var bigArray = [
   [1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
   [7,8,9],
   [10,11,12]
];

for(var i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
   for(var j = 0; j < bigArray[i].length; j++) {
      console.log(bigArray[i][j]); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, '.length' method will return the total number elements in that array, But array index starts from 0. So if an array contains n elements the array index of the last element will be n-1. And if you are trying to access an array with index n it will return an ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception.
You can try this code

```
var bigArray = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11, 12]
];
for (i = 0; i <= bigArray.length-1; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j <= bigArray[i].length-1; j++) {
    console.log(bigArray[i][j]);
  }
}
```